# How to create a custom histogram (normalized)

Tags: list-manipulation, data, histograms

Let's create some sample data

```
n = 1000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-2, 2}], RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 
RandomInteger[{0, 100}]}, {i, 0, n}];
datan = Table[data[[i, 3]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
```

Now we plot a [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) showing how many times every integer (third element of the list) appears.

[image]

The histogram is fine however in the vertical axis it shows the absolute values. For example the integer $20$ appears $n = 92$ times.

**I want the relative values in the vertical axis. The relative value is the absolute value n divided by the total number $N$ (in this example $N = 1000$).**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

```
Histogram[datan, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To show the most common value in the Histogram, I define an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) with a `Red` [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) at the $x$ position of the [`Commonest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Commonest.html) value.

```
Histogram[
 datan
 , Automatic
 , "Probability"
 , Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@Last@Commonest[datan]]}
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@Last@Commonest[datan]
```

> ```
> {{59, 0}, {59, 1}}
> ```

## Documentation

[`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very quick and elegant! Any chance showing the average value on the histogram?

Comment: You mean the average height of the bins? @Vaggelis_Z

Comment: I would like to show (preferable with a vertical line) the n integer with the highest probability.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Next time please avoid moving the goalpost and state your needs specifically in the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 3):

rhermans [shows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107677/9490) a nice built-in way to make this particular histogram, but you can make any custom histogram by the following method.

You can extract the original data from `HistogramList`,

```
n = 1000;
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-2, 2}], RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 
    RandomInteger[{0, 100}]}, {i, 0, n}];
datan = Table[data[[i, 3]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
Histogram@datan
histdata = HistogramList@datan
```

[image]

```
(*{{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110}, {98, 91, 102, 109, 88, 103, 94, 111, 104, 93, 8}*)
```

Now you can do whatever transformations you like on this.  For this example

```
histdata = {#1, #2/1000} & @@ histdata
(* {{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110}, {1/10, 
  21/200, 29/250, 101/1000, 51/500, 49/500, 43/500, 49/500, 87/1000, 
  89/1000, 19/1000}} *)
```

and then use this function to make a custom histogram,

```
histogram[{bins_, bincounts_}, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{width = First@Differences@bins}, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], RGBColor[0.98, 0.8, 0.49], 
     Rectangle[{#1 - 0.5 width, 0}, {#1 + 0.5 width, #2}] & @@@ 
      Transpose[{Mean /@ (Partition[bins, 2, 1]), bincounts}]}, 
    plotopts, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.7]];

histogram[histdata]
```

[image]